# compile php one time for allways

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

1. I am making php program to run on local network and I want to give it to some other peoples to use. but I don't want to ask them to install XAMPP or other programs like this. (XAMPP is about 100 MB and they cant download it) is there any other way to make Apache and MySQL server easier on a system. for example they run a batch file and the file make server on port 80 and copy my scripts on its htdocs (or something like this) folder.
2. My second problem in XAMPP is PhpMyAdmin, which allow all devices in local network to manage my program databases and change them. I need a trick to disable PhpMyAdmin in client devices.

Sorry for bad English. :)

Comment: tell them to access your web server by an IP, e.g., `http://192.168.1.1/something.php`

Comment: sounds like you picked the wrong language to start with

Comment: this is not possible.

Comment: but i need to use it on local network and easiest language for net programs is php.

Comment: Do you want to build a desktop app with php?

Comment: Something like this but my app should accessible from more than one device in local network. Actually  it's a bank which made for a competition named ArithLand [read here about it](http://mirzavaziri.ir/arithland/docs/arithland.EN.pdf) and in this competition we have about 10 laptops with bankers and they store the teams money (the currency is proof) and the laptops should connected.

Comment: You may want to look http://gtk.php.net/ .. But there is a lack of documentation..

Comment: http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/html/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xampp on windows is set to allow phpmyadmin from your local network. To disable access from your network, Open httpd-xampp.conf located in xampp-folder\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf Somewhere down in the bottom of this configuration file is the LocationMatch node Even though you would think the default Order is set to deny, allow with Deny from all. This configuration by default is set to Allow from 192.168.0.#. Remove this ip range and you are set. Change this

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 \
fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Don’t forget to restart Apache. Now http://localhost/phpmyadmin will result 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: Thanks, now is there any way to access PhpMyAdmin on server computer when it's not accessible in other local network devices, and also my project stay accessible from all devices?

Comment: yes your project is accessible from all devices this code only disable to access phpmyadmin not your project...and you can access phpmyadmin by entering 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

If your computer and the other computers(computers which like to access) in the same network, the other computers can have access to the web application from the browser by inserting **localhost/yourproject** to **[your-ip-address]/yourproject**. Not only computer but also from your mobile device.

The only and the other way is hosting on the web.

Comment: yes. I know they have access to my web application and I like it because it's a net application . My problem is about PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: check it out it is the configuration of xamp not to access the other computer from the local network to your project... but careful with dat...